# "invalid use of ‘struct main()" when using getline and hierarchical structures

Tags: c++

I know I'm probably overlooking something pretty simple but I'm about to go crazy over here.

I haven't had a problem with getline so far until hierarchical structures.

When I have

```
struct top_level
{
    struct employee_name
    {
        string employee_title;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
    };

    struct employee_address
    {
        string num_street;
        string city_state;
        string zip_code;
    };

    struct employee_phone
    {
        string home_phone;
        string cell_phone;
        string work_phone;
    };
};

struct top_level employee_1;
getline (inFile, employee_1.employee_name.employee_title);
```

(the values being read are strings)

The filestream works alright, but the error I get when compiling is

> "error: invalid use of ‘struct main()::top_level::employee_phone’"

for every getline; it seems to have a problem with the middle layer of structures.

I'm not asking for anybody to write me any code, I'm just stumped by this error.

If anybody has any ideas I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct top_level declares sub-structs, but does not have members. You need to write

```
struct top_level
{
    struct employee_name
    {
        string employee_title;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
    } employee_name;

    struct employee_address
    {
        string num_street;
        string city_state;
        string zip_code;
    } employee_address;

    struct employee_phone
    {
        string home_phone;
        string cell_phone;
        string work_phone;
    } employee_phone;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `top_level` is empty, i.e. it has no data members. It only has a few member *types*.

Comment: Does the declaration 

struct top_level employee_1;

not remedy this problem though?

Comment: @user2945132 No, that just creates an instance of the empty class `top_level`.

Comment: Oh alright; so I would remedy this by declaring the substructures in some way?

Comment: @user2945132: You remedy it by *adding member definitions* to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your top_level structure does not contain data members. It contains only type definitions.